# Editing an item in a dialog and next refreshing the current page showed (and not jump back to page 1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a solution with ASP.NET MVC3. I have a page where we can manage users (create/edit/remove). I have paging on this page.

[image]

When edit button is pressed, a dialog is showed where editing is possible.

[image]

When user click the save button, the dialog is hided and the list is refresh through ajax.

The problem occurred when user edit an item on page 2 or 3 or ... In this case, the page 1 is showed. The reason is that the current page information is not known in my action's controller.  I would like to keep the currectly active page in my view.

Here is the solution I have but not quite satisfied with:

On my edit button I have the ActionLink below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Editer", "Edit", new { userID = item.UserID }, new { userID = item.UserID, page = Model.PageNumber, @class = "btn small editUser" })
```

I inject the page number in my anchor link. Next the dialog is shown. Next user click save (submitting). The submit action is triggered and the page number is injected in the post parameters like this:

```
$('form', dialog).submit(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize() + '&page=2', function (data, status) {
            $('#my-modal').modal('hide');
            $("#userList").html(data);
    })
});
```

As you can see I manually added '&page=2' for testing purpose. The action in my controller receive the posted data (edited item + page number) updated my repository then RedirectToAction("List", new {page = page}) refresh the list for the right page.

I don't like this solution. There must be a better way of doing, isn't?

Thanks in advance if someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Wether you have a complete "Ajax grid", which you can refresh without refreshing page, or you have a "server side" grid, than you need to reload page, and your solution is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by a complete 'ajax grid' ? Sorry this is the first time I try to implement that kind of thing. I'm a bit lost :(

Comment: Well it means that refresh happens on client side, not server side (javascript is used to do the refreshing job)

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. I would prefer the server side solution but I lost the page number in my case. I think this is a trivial scenario but I'm not able to resolve it :(

Comment: You can use the Model.PageNumber in your javascript, I think... then it won't be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, instead of returning the whole grid, just update the row with the new data.  I do this on my search/edit pages.  When the user clicks a row, store that row index in javascript.  Then after a successful edit, update the row with the values from the textboxes.

Comment: Updating only the edited row is possible. I don't know if this is the only solution. If possible (and reasonable) I prefer updating the entire 1st, 2nd, ...'page'